# Hackerrank Java Map Question Timeout Problem

Tags: java, hashmap, printf

I have solved hackerrank Java Map Problem but I had timeout result for 2 cases. When I changed just the printf line problem solved. However I could not understand why it is ? Here my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{

private static HashMap<String, Integer> phoneBook = new HashMap<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String search = "";

    int n=in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        String name=in.nextLine();
        int phone=in.nextInt();
        phoneBook.put(name, phone);
        in.nextLine();
    }

    while(in.hasNext()) {
        search = in.nextLine();
        if (phoneBook.get(search) != null)
            System.out.printf(search + "=" + phoneBook.get(search) + "\n"); // this works 
            // System.out.printf("%s=%d\n", search, phoneBook.get(search)); // this does not work why ?
        else
            System.out.println("Not found");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `Formatter.format()` takes time

`Formatter.format()` (and its shortcut `System.out.printf()`) requires parsing, validating and formatting. All that takes a huge amount of time.

So just dump the data as quick as possible. Hackerrank requires you to make fast programs, so just do that: a fast program. Concatenate your items instead of formatting them. Also, if you have no parameter, just use `System.out.println()` instead of `System.out.printf`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a formatting output, java parses the string to format (`"%s=%d\n"` in your case) to put values instead placeholders. It takes at least `O(n)` complexity, which is important in your case.

Also you call `phoneBook.get(search)` twice. Try to keep the result in a variable. It also can speed up the program.

Answer (score 0):

To break the string into separate lines, we need to use %n specifier in printf statement.

```
System.out.printf("%s=%d%n", search, phoneBook.get(search));
```

OR you can use the String.format() shown in the below statement.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s=%d",s,p));
```

Comment: I doubt that using `%n` is faster than using `\n` (as it requires at least one more parsing step), also hard to believe that second line is faster than first (using `\n` instead of `%n`)

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Lookup performance of Hashmap + Formatting the fetched value from the HashMap was computationally more Intensive than just concatenating the string without any format.

To be a bit verbose, the HashMap Implementation which is designed for an amortized complexity of O(1) for get(Key) functions does have a nasty complexity of **O(n)** (**stressing the term worst case :)** ) if either all or most of the keys share a common hash. Such occurrences, although not very common would've occurred when the test case feeder gave an enormous test case input with multiple duplicate values. Such a situation combined with simultaneous formatting would've resulted in a crash.